# The security of Zero knowledge proof performance

Tags: security, encryption, proof

I recently learned to study the security of zero-knowledge proofs.

It seems from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof), that the most popular example is the Ali Baba cave. I have a question about the security of the zero-knowledge proof for the Ali Baba cave.

During the verification process, the Prover will deliver the value of

```
e = [0,1 ...]
```

And `e` will have a solution to either `left` or `right` depending on `0` or `1`. And according to the length of list `e`, this process is said to have a security complexity of `O(2 ^ n)`. However, there are only two paths, and depending on the value of e, the secret key value is not changed in directions A and B. So, should not the safety of this algorithm be just `O(2)`?

Comment: You may rather ask on crypto.stackexchange.com , you may get there answer from people who actually understand it :) On the programming forum your question very probably will get downvoted or closed.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize this site. I will be delete this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ali Baba cave comprises the following scenario:

1. Peggy chooses a random path (A, or B), without any information from Victor.
2. Victor asks (shouts, in the cave) Peggy to exit the cave from one of the two ends (A or B), without knowing the enter path chosen by Peggy.
3. Peggy exits through the path chosen by Victor.

For a single proof, this has the same probability as random chance:
If we call `P_in` the path where Peggy entered and `V_out` the path that Victor asks Peggy to go out to,

- If `P_in = V_out`, then Peggy can trivially exit the cave without knowing how to open the door inside.
- If `P_in != V_out`, then Peggy needs to know the key to cross from one side of the cave to the other.

We have the following equiprobable scenarios:

- P_in = A, V_out = A
- P_in = A, V_out = B
- P_in = B, V_out = A
- P_in = B, V_out = B

They are equiprobable because Peggy chooses randomly, and Victor chooses randomly without knowing what Peggy chose (that is the zero-knowledge part).

From the prior assumption, we easily get that `P(P_in = V_out) = 1/2`: that is, the probability of Peggy being able to trivially exit the cave without additional knowledge is the same as random chance.

However, if Victor *repeatedly* ask Peggy to go inside of the cave, probabilities multiply. That is, `P_in#1 = V_out#1 = 50%`; but `P_in#2 = V_out#2 = 50%` (by itself), which means, due to conditional probability (assuming the events are independent) that, in order to get both times out the cave by random chance:

```
P(P_in#1 = V_out#1 /\ P_in#2 = V_out#2) = 1/2 * 1/2 = 1/4
```

The probability of Peggy knowing the key has now raised to 3/4:

```
P( (P_in#1 != V_out#1 /\ P_in#2 == V_out#2)
|| (P_in#1 == V_out#1 /\ P_in#2 != V_out#2)
|| (P_in#1 != V_out#1 /\ P_in#2 != V_out#2)) =

P( ((P_in#1 != V_out#1 || P_in#1 == V_out#1) /\ P_in#2 == V_out#2)
|| P_in#1 != V_out#1 /\ P_in#2 != V_out#2) =

P( P_in#2 == V_out#2
|| (P_in#1 != V_out#1 /\ P_in#2 != V_out#2)) = 1/2 + (1/2 * 1/2) = 3/4
```

The reason behind the exponential complexity lies in that a *single failure* establishes distrust, while accumulating a "winning streak" by random chance is exponentially difficult. Thus, given the prior probabilities, you get `O(2 ^ n)` since you get "times two" the difficulty on each attempt.